# mono cannot access to the directory or file name contains unicode characters(non-ASCII)?

Tags: unicode, mono, directory

[Mono 3.2.1]

Use the Directory.GetFileSystemEntries or Directory.GetDirectories method cannot obtain chinese directory.Why?

Are there any ways to solve this problems?

[for example]

directory structure:

```
  Contents
      |--zipfile
             |--sub
             |--1.txt
             |--中文.txt
             |--中文
                 |--2.txt
```

code:

```
string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(Server.MapPath("~/Content/zipfile"));
```

Cannot get the "中文" directory and the "中文.txt" file.

Comment: post some code! a simple, complete example that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

works for me:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ mcs -o test.csx test.cs
warning CS8029: Compatibility: Use -out:FILE instead of --output FILE or -o FILE
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ mkdir  漢語
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ ls
bitcoin.tmp       litecoin.tmp    pulse-2L9K88eMlGn7  test.cs   漢語
CRX_75DAF8CB7768  pcaresult.html  pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n  test.csx
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ mono ./test.csx
./.ICE-unix
./.X0-lock
./.X11-unix
./.google-talk-plugin-jcomeau.lock
./.org.chromium.Chromium.kFgd2O
./CRX_75DAF8CB7768
./bitcoin.tmp
./litecoin.tmp
./pcaresult.html
./pulse-2L9K88eMlGn7
./pulse-PKdhtXMmr18n
./test.cs
./test.csx
./漢語
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ cat test.cs
using System;
using System.IO;
public class Test {
 static public void Main() {
  foreach (String filename in Directory.GetFileSystemEntries(".")) {
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", filename);
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: But i cannot. My OS is Debian 6. Any settings? locale or language?

Comment: what do you see when you run this program in a directory with unicode Chinese directory names? please post output. (I'm running Debian 7.1)

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XTERM_LOCALE=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: FindNextFile: Bad encoding for './中文'
Consider using MONO_EXTERNAL_ENCODINGS

Comment: search this page for MONO_EXTERNAL_ENCODINGS for usage: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical

Comment: maybe

$export MONO_EXTERNAL_ENCODINGS="big5"

will do it. just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's should be using zh_CN.UTF-8. I have changed the 'HAVE_LOCALCHARSET_H ' When mono is compiled, fllow this:<a href='http://serverfault.com/questions/249411/mono-undefined-reference-to-locale-charset'>Mono undefined reference to `locale_charset'</a>

Comment: HAVE_LOCALCHARSET_H is a problem?

Comment: perhaps. this question is now substantively different from the one I answered. you should probably do some more research and post a new question.